# HighCharts: set specific border width and border color dynamically for one column

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I would like to change dynamically the border width and border color of only one of the columns in a basic column chart similar to the following:

```
var chartingOptions = {
chart: {
    renderTo: 'container',
    type: 'column'
},
xAxis: {
    categories: ['5:1', '4:1', '3:1', '2:1', '1:1', '1:2', '1:3', '1:4', '1:5']
},
plotOptions: {
    column: {           
      grouping: false
    }
},
series: [
    {
    name: 'Serie 2',
    data: [20, 24, 30, 40, 60, 80, 90, 96, 100]},
{
    name: 'Serie 1',
    data: [100, 96, 90, 80, 60, 40, 30, 24, 20]}
            ]
};

var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(chartingOptions);
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/garrickcheung/67BkD/19/) here.

I tried to changed it for the first serie directly through

```
chart.series[0].data[2].series.borderColor = 'black'
```

but it does not update the serie. Anything helps!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to refer to the SVG element and manipulate `stroke` and `stroke-width` paraemters.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/usLuzrwn/3/

Comment: This is exactly what I need. I tried with borderWidth as well but it does not work. Any idea why?

Comment: See my new answer, indeed better is edit graphic element, because border can be updated only on the entire serie, not per particular point. So check the workaround.

Comment: There is an issue with this solution - if you hover over the column, the border color gets reset.  BTW, Took me a while to realize that I needed to click the "Update" button! :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`chart.series[0].data[2].series.borderColor = 'black'` will not do anything. Instead try 
`chart.series[0].data[2].series.color = 'black'` but this will also change the color of tooltip.

In order to change color of one column explicitly try as

`data: [{
    name: 'Point 1',
    color: '#00FF00',
    y: 0
}, {
    name: 'Point 2',
    color: '#FF00FF',
    y: 5
}]`

For more information check here http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data.color

You can refer this [fiddle] http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/column-bordercolor/

Comment: Thanks but this does not answer my question. This changes the color, neither the border width nor the border color. I made my question more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

The borderColor and borderWidth properties are available for series object and not for data object. As I mentioned you can check the documentation for the same in above link.

However you can force data object to have borderColor and borderWidth by defining these properties in source code of highcharts.js.

Hope this info helps.

Comment: Dont duplicate answers, because you can edit one and add any details.